# iocpreactor release status in twisted

Tags: windows, twisted, io-completion-ports, twisted.internet

we are having issues with the default select reactor on Windows 2008. There is an alternative reactor, the iocpreactor, that looks like an ideal solution for Windows. it is listed in the documentation as experimental, and 'nearly ready'.

What does this mean in real terms? So far we have tested it without issue. Is it in general use? can anyone else recommend it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That documentation is probably out of date.  The main limitation of the IOCP reactor was the lack of SSL support, which was addressed [4 years ago](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/593).  Many people have been using it successfully for a long time; it shouldn't be described as "experimental".

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried the iocpreactor in our development setup and found an immediate problem. I opened ticket http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6217. i also had the issue already logged with http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5562 Both of these issues are critical for our application and neither are resolved in 12.3

Comment: Thanks for all your help diagnosing those issues.